# How to log request_body with traefik?

Tags: post, logging, request, traefik

How to config traefik to log request_body in logfile?

my config file is as below:

```
traefik.toml 

logLevel="INFO"

defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[accessLog]
format = "json"
```

Answer (score 2):

Traefik doesn't support this feature.

And what is maybe even more important, it was decided to not support this feature. You can check the reasons here: https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/6704